# AG-Grid cell value sum update to its parent row without grid refresh on server-side-model-tree-data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have used ag-grid server-side-model-tree-data and i'm updating cell value to its parent using "onCellValueChanged".

I have total value function but Unfortunately it does not update to parent without grid refresh.

i need help to update cell value sum without refresh.

Used function when cell value edit

```
const onCellValueChanged = (event) => {
let tree = createTree(event.node);
let address = createAddress(tree, props.subItem).address;
let payload = { ...props.subItem };
let data = eval(`payload.${address}.budgets`);
let budgets = [
   {
    budgetValues: {
      JANUARY: event.data.janBudget,
      FEBRUARY: event.data.febBudget,
      MARCH: event.data.marBudget,
      APRIL: event.data.aprBudget,
      MAY: event.data.mayBudget,
      JUNE: event.data.junBudget,
      JULY: event.data.julBudget,
      AUGUST: event.data.augBudget,
      SEPTEMBER: event.data.sepBudget,
      OCTOBER: event.data.octBudget,
      NOVEMBER: event.data.novBudget,
      DECEMBER: event.data.decBudget,
    }
];
data = eval(`payload.${address}.budgets=budgets`);
const result = updateParentBudget(payload, props.selectedBudget.value);
props.handleUpdate(result);
```

};

total calculation function

```
function updateParentBudget(jsonData, budgetKey = "budgetValues") {
// console.log('jsonData', jsonData);
if (jsonData.subCategories && jsonData.subCategories.length > 0) {
  jsonData.budgets[budgetKey] = Object.keys(jsonData.budgets[budgetKey]).reduce((acc, month) => {
    acc[month] = jsonData.subCategories.reduce((sum, subCategory) => {
      const childBudget = updateParentBudget(subCategory);
      // console.log('childBudget', childBudget)
      return parseInt(sum) + parseInt(childBudget.budgets[budgetKey][month]);
    }, 0);
    return acc;
  }, jsonData.budgets[budgetKey]);
}

return jsonData;
```

}

Comment: Can you make an example here? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new